# How can I check a few parametres in this strpos line?

Tags: php, strpos

`if (strpos($text,'City') !== false)` ...

In that "IF" line, I wanna check a few parametres. For example "City, Weather, etc" How can i do that?

Edit: Thank you for all answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it another way by using in_array() function.

```
$array = array('City','Weather','anything');
if (in_array($text, $array)) {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(strpos($text,'City') !== false && strpos($text,'Weather') !== false && ...)
```

Trivial, really.

Answer (score 1):

[Kolinks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17146329/247893) is completely correct and very trivial. If you prefer to use an array, you can do as such as well:

Your typical `OR` or `||` replacement:

```
<?php
    $text = "I live in a City with some very bad Weather etc.";

    $searchWords = array("City", "Weather", "etc");
    $found = false;
    foreach ($searchWords as $searchWord) {
        if (strpos($text, $searchWord) !== false) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($found) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        //Didn't find anything
    }
?>
```

Your typical `AND` or `&&` replacement:

```
<?php
    $text = "I live in a City with some very bad Weather etc.";

    $searchWords = array("City", "Weather", "etc");
    $found = true; //start at true instead of false
    foreach ($searchWords as $searchWord) {
        if (strpos($text, $searchWord) === false) { //=== instead of !==
            $found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($found) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        //Didn't find anything
    }
?>
```

Comment: It only checks 1 word among many, not all of them.

Comment: checking 1 word among is what I need .)

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "I live in a City with some very bad Weather etc.";

$searchWords = array("City", "Weather", "etc");
$finds = array();
foreach ($searchWords as $searchWord) {
    if (strpos($text, $searchWord) !== false) {
        !isset($finds[$searchWord]) and ($finds[$searchWord] = 0);
        $finds[$searchWord]++; // increment finds
    }
}
if (count($finds) === count($searchWords)) {
    // found ALL words
}elseif (!empty($finds)) {
    // found SOME words
} else {
    // found NO words
}
```

Improved on [h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo)'s answer a bit. Handles AND/OR for searched keywords.

Comment: If the word "City" is found 2 times and "Weather" none it will say "found all words", but they were not all here.

Comment: @Savageman You're right! Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I utilize a custom function I always use for this kind of problem. I'll share it with you.

```
function in_array_stripos($needle_array, $word) {
   foreach($needle_array as $needle) {
      if (stripos($word, $needle) !== false) {
         return true;
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Usage syntax:

```
if (in_array_stripos(array('City', 'Weather'), $text)) {
   // text contains these words
}
```

Comment: It only checks 1 word among many, not all of them.

And for conventions, I would name the function `strpos_array()` which tells better what the function does compared to `in_arrayi()` which make me think it looks if the string is one of the word of the array in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: @Savageman You're wrong. OP wants the function to return true if **either** of the words exist in the string (thus OR, not AND). Also changed the function name.